# how to add optional parameter to laravel named routes?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2 and according to [routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)

We can define a named route as

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

And define an optional parameter with this other way

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = null)
{
    return $name;
});
```

I want to add an optional parameter to a named route. How to combine both ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it with one route. But you can do it with two pointing to the same controller method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = null)
{
    return $name;
})->name('foo');
```

## Update

sorry the name method not exists in Laravel 4.2
You can do it in another way

```
Route::get('user/profile/{name?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'))
```

#### or

```
Route::get('user/profile/{name?}', array('as' => 'profile', function($name = null) {
// your code here 
})
```

Comment: This is not a named route. It is trying to call route 'name'. I want to select a Controller and his method with optional parameter.

Comment: In laravel 5.4 you can call the name method to naming the route :)

Comment: super that s what I was looking for. Only I ve to wait a bit to accept your answer.

Comment: great, thanks a lot, don't forget to mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can define route common for all functions..
like:

```
Route::controller('uses', 'UserController');
```

And define function with optional parameters:

```
  public function getView($param = 0)
     //your code here
   }
```

using this you can use optional parameters in a function on which you required.with help of ajax call on function.